# Appcelerator organization suddenly inactive

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I know it usually takes a really long time to get a reply from anyone at Appcelerator but it is quite disastrous for us.

Our platform organization has suddenly became inactive.

Out of the blue, we can not run apps on simulators and all the apps on the platform are Zero. We can not track anything!

We have several apps already published. Having them suddenly disappearing is inexplainable.

What to do?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to hear this. Are you https://twitter.com/IGCSEWorld? Am I correct we're in touch with you to handle this now?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to a company I worked for once.  We would log into the platform and it would show 0/0 apps, plus none of the services.  We contacted Appcelerator and they quickly realized there was a server issue which was pointing our team to the wrong dashboard.  I know they may be slow in responding but that is your best bet for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift reply.
Appcelerator's support is extremely slow, unresponsive and I just wonder if they know that many of the developers are indie and they NEED help on faster rate and larger scale.